# Youtube API on clicking a different times does BUFFERING (state=3) always occur?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am using the Youtube API and was wondering if anyone knew if when you click the youtube player's time (at the bottom of the video) to progress/or go back to an earlier point in the video if the BUFFERING, or state=3 value always occur?

For example:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    //video is buffering, one cause is the user 
    //clicked to progress/go back in the video.
    //Does buffering state always happen in this case?
    if (event.data == 3) {
       //BUFFERING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is intended to fire 3 (buffering) due to `onStateChange` when pressing play button or player's time. As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events), event fires whenever the player's state changes. The `data` property of the event object that the API passes your evnt listener function will specifiy an integer that corresponds to the new player state. Below are the possible values:

- -1 (unstarted)
- 0 (ended)
- 1 (playing)
- 2 (paused)
- 3 (buffering)
- 5 (video cued).